# font-size using em or px?

Tags: html, css

How big I should set to the site's body,the `h1` , `h2`, and the paragraph font-size?

Comment: What does this have to do with SEO?

Comment: @BoltClock: Nothing. Retagged.

Comment: There is no correct answer to this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**In short: it depends what you want to achieve and taste**

For readibility purpose, you should use what already have you pre setted in your browser and do not touch anything, but in reality we all modify the size of the font on what we think that work or like best.

**EM would be better** for controlling the flexibility of the resize of text, but **you must be aware to not nest various EM measurement**. For example if I say

body{font-size:0.8em} and later I write p{font-size:0.8em}, I have done that the font

it is reduced 2 times proportionally so it is like 1*0.8*0.8 which if you keep increasing or decreasing it could lead in big problems of resizing with the other text.

**PX it is ok** as well, now recent browser resize easily the browser and allow to override the PX definition and resizing the content (I think that the only that doesn't do that was IE upt to the IE8, but I do not know about IE9)

My suggestion is use a [fibonacci proportion](http://3.7designs.co/blog/2010/10/how-to-design-using-the-fibonacci-sequence/comment-page-1/) or at least keep a difference between font-size of 2/3px from H1, h2, h3 etc... down to

Here there is a more complete and better reading about what people are using, and what are some scale
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/20/typographic-design-survey-best-practices-from-the-best-blogs/

and a good article about it from A list apart: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/howtosizetextincss/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ems, you can set...

```
body {
   font-size: 62.5%
}
```

To make `1em` roughly `10px`.

Otherwise, what value you want them is up to you, but do try to keep in mind the semantic meaning of `h1`, `h2`, etc. For example, `h1` *should* be more visually important (bigger font size, brighter colour, etc) than `h2`, and so forth.